# Slow Router Speeds

Tags: networking, router

I've been encountering a weird issue with routers in my house where the wired speeds slow down to around 50mb/s instead of the 500-600mb/s I get when directly connected . This first happened on a ~5 year old Airport Extreme which I just chalked up to random failure, but I've since had the same thing happen with a Netgear AC1600 and I'm trying to figure out what might be happening.

Our ISP provides an ONT modem but in the closet - so I have two switches setup with VLANs so that I can have my router in the living room as below [image: this image describes it best]. We use a ton of data each day (60GB / day at peak), so I don't know if these routers are just underpowered and eventually fry themselves somehow.

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Comment: Is everything connecting at 1Gbps? Sounds like there could be a link somewhere that's only running at 100MBps. Can't go faster than the slowest pipe after all.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, everything is at 1Gbps.

Comment: You should try testing leg-to-leg just to make sure there is no bottleneck. You'd need two PCs and iperf and just switch out where each is connected to just make sure there is nothing slowing things down at any hop. You might also try changing channels on the wireless as there may be something that periodically interferes with the frequency you're using.

Comment: I've confirmed the bottleneck is traffic to the internet - internal traffic can max out an ethernet link. All of my testing has been done over wired ethernet, though iperf testing over wireless doesn't indicate an issue there either.

Comment: Anything logged on the switches? Can you swap the switches over see if the problem continues? Can you try a different port on the switch, swap out cables? Are these good quality switches?

Comment: Nope, they're both silent - if I directly connect to the switch port that's on the public VLAN (or directly to the ONT) I see the speeds I expect. Both switches are Netgear ProSafe Gigabit Switches - one is a GS108T and the other is a GS305. The cables are in-wall so I can't switch them out, but I don't suspect them since I can hit ~870mb/s between computers on each switch.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up figuring out that a firmware update to my modem caused the issue (thanks AT&T). It only affected machines set to receive the public IP which is why it wasn't more obvious.